# GWT ClickHandler

Tags: java, gwt, widget

This is how I try to realize a simple product list (`FlexTable`) with some buttons to add, edit and delete products.

My Problem is the `ClickHandler`. In other projects I saw that they always used nested classes for defining the click handler (like below). It works but I don't understand why. When I try to define the `ClickHandler` within the above class, there always occurs an (Syntax) error.

I'm a beginner and it would be great to get some help here. Thank you!

```
package com.example.itprojektv2.client;

import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;

public class ShowProducts extends Showcase {

    /*
     * Instantiate GUI Elements
     */

    private FlexTable productTable = new FlexTable(); 
    public Button addBt = new Button("Add");
    public Button editBt = new Button("Edit");
    public Button deleteBt = new Button("Delete");


    /*
     * Override abstract methods
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected String getHeadlineText() {
        return "Product - List";
    }

    @Override
    protected void run() {
        this.add(productTable); 

        productTable.setHTML(0, 0, "<h2>ID</h2>");
        productTable.setHTML(0, 1, "<h2>Name</h2>");
        productTable.setHTML(0, 2, "<h2>Price</h2>");
        productTable.setHTML(0, 3, "<h2></h2>");
        productTable.setWidget(1, 3, addBt);
        productTable.setWidget(1, 4, editBt);
        productTable.setWidget(1, 5, deleteBt);

        editBt.addClickHandler(new EditProductClickHandler());
    }


    /**
     * Nested-Class for the Click - Handling on "edit Product"
     */

    private class EditProductClickHandler implements ClickHandler {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            EditProduct edit = new EditProduct();

            RootPanel.get("Content").clear(); 
            RootPanel.get("Content").add(edit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the syntax error you get?

Comment: "Syntax error on token "addClickHandler", invalid AnnotationName" This shows up when i try to add the Handler on the top after instantiating the Button.

Comment: You usually get that error when there's code outside of a method. That's not the case in the code you posted. Is this the whole class you posted or is there more to it?